# Excel VBA: call sub when change to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Pretty basic question. I'm looking for a sub which will be triggered when the user changes the active worksheet to a certain worksheet (calles worksheet3).

Doing some research in the internet could not help me, unfortunately.

The event sub I am looking for should be very similar to the `workbook_open` sub. Obviously it is triggered everytime the workbook opens. So my question: is there a similar event sub which is triggered when I open a certain worksheet? Kind of like `worksheet3_open`?

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4424-excel-run-macro-when-sheet-is-selected.html

Comment: Use: `Worksheet_Activate`

Comment: So basically the keywords to search for are "worksheet" and "activate" and not "select" or "open".  Hopefully that should get you a quick answer to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Nothing on the net????? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Worksheet_Activate()` event in the Worksheet3 code page.

1. Choose your worksheet by double clicking in the PRoject window:

   [image]
2. From the drop down at the top, choose "Worksheet"

   [image]
3. From the second drop down just to the right choose "Activate".

   [image]

You'll have a new subroutine created called `Worksheet_Activate()` that will fire every time that tab is activated by the user.

You can then call your subroutine inside of that code so it runs as well.

Comment: could you please edit the sub name 'worksheet_active' to 'worksheet_activate' as you refering below. thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks @J.schmidt. Totally fat fingered that one!

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code under your workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    If Sh.Name = "worksheet3" Then
        YourSub
    End If

End Sub
```